# The HTML element is not covering the page

Tags: html, css

So, I have a weird problem here that I'm not sure why it exists. I'm working on a webpage and was adding in a background image by centering it with no-repeat, like so. This is from an external CSS

```
body {
    background-image: url('AllCalcBackground.png');
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The overflow is just because I don't want scrollbars on the page and the margins is so that everything can lie flush with the sides of the window if I want. Anyway, for some reason the image is deciding to center NOT in the center of the page, but near the top. I inspected the page (as in pressing F12 in the browser to check the code) and it says that my HTML and body elements are actually taking up the top 131px of the webpage, and I have no idea why. Nothing is affecting either of them except for this CSS for the body element, they are simply fitting themselves to the content currently on the page as opposed to filling the page like I expect they are supposed to. Does anyone know why or can help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
body { 
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   background: url(AllCalcBackground.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

This CSS will stop overflow and fit your image as static to the background so even when you scroll it will stay in its position.

Comment: I tried that but the image was bigger than I wanted, I wanted it to fit to the page. I changed the 'cover' to '100% 100%' but it just made them repeat down the page at the height that the weird HTML element currently is

Comment: try the changes I've made to my first answer...

Oh and if this doesn't work give us a JSFiddle of what you want and I'll do it there...

Answer (score 0):

You can center the image in the browser like this:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
body {
    background: url(AllCalcBackground.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

If you want the image to fill the viewport, then try this:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
body {
    background: url(AllCalcBackground.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I did have to manually set the html to 100% height and width to make it set up the way I wanted, but I'm not sure why I HAD to do that because as I recall the HTML element is supposed to automatically be 100% of the browser size

Comment: It's common (and completely safe) to set the html and body elements to height: 100% for things like sticky footers etc., so it is needed to get the result you want.